# jquery multiselect code resetting other form fields

Tags: jquery, html

I have an assign/revoke roles page that provides a select field to choose the role and two multiselect fields to contain those users currently unassigned or assigned.  Two buttons allow you to move users between the "assign" and "revoke" multiselect fields.  Finally, two submit buttons allow you to save or cancel your changes.

Everything works except that when you press one of the add/remove buttons, which fires off some jquery to move the highlighted entries between the multiselects, it ends up resetting the role select field to the default (first) entry.

The page looks something like:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="userroles" id="userroles">
  <table>
    <tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><h2>Assign/Revoke Roles</h2><br />
    Choose Role: 
    <select id="role" name="role">
      <option value="1" selected>Blah</option>
          .
          .
          .
    </select> <input type="submit" name="action" value="Select Role"><br /><br /></td>
    <tr><td colspan="3" align="center">
        Assigning Role:  <strong>Blah</strong></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Unassigned</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Assigned</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><select multiple id="unassigned" name="unassigned" class="multiselect">
      <option value="11111">some</option>
      <option value="22222">people</option>
      <option value="33333">here</option>
      </select></td>
      <td>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="&gt;&gt"><br /><br /><br />
    <input type="button" id="remove" value="&lt;&lt">
      </td>
      <td><select multiple id="assigned" name="assigned" class="multiselect">
      <option value="44444">other</option>
      <option value="55555">people</option>
      <option value="66666">here</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="action" value="Save">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

The jquery looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $().ready(function() {  
    $('#add').click(function() {  
      !$('#unassigned option:selected').remove().appendTo('#assigned');
      return $("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");  
    });  
    $('#remove').click(function() {  
      !$('#assigned option:selected').remove().appendTo('#unassigned');
      return $("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");  
    });
    $('form').submit(function() {
      $('#unassigned option').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
      });
      $('#assigned option').each(function(i) {  
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");  
      });  
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

The jquery has two functions that move the selected entries between multiselects and a third function that highlights all entries on both multiselects so that all data from both multiselects can be sent back via a POST.

Is there anyway to have the jquery no reset or preserve the currently selected role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The add/remove button handlers call

```
$("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

which removes selected from *all* options, including the ones at the top.

Try this instead

```
$('#add').click(function() {  
  !$('#unassigned option:selected').remove().appendTo('#assigned');
  return $("#assigned option:selected").removeAttr("selected");  
});  

$('#remove').click(function() {  
  !$('#assigned option:selected').remove().appendTo('#unassigned');
  return $("#unassigned option:selected").removeAttr("selected");  
});
```

Comment: The add/remove buttons are not submit buttons, only the "Save, Cancel" buttons are.  When I first started having this problem I double-checked to make sure they were not submit buttons.  These buttons are only processed by the jquery script and are only being processed client-side.

Comment: yes, that's the same answer I got over a jquery.com.  I was about to post the answer here but you beat me to it ;)